# Unable to match 2 elements with one element having null value

Tags: python, selenium, for-loop

I am trying to match the name and the sold quantity attribute of product listed on the this site: my site (as an example)
However, there is some product items not having sold quantity element. Exactly, that element is not displayed because that shop has not sold any such item.
I try to scrape and match product name (@class='name_product shop_color_hover') and sold quantity (@class='s_b').
Here are my working:

```
from selenium import webdriver
.......
element_name='//*[@class="name_product shop_color_hover"]'
element_price='//*[@class="current_price"]'
element_sold='//*[@class="s_b"]'
link='https://www.sendo.vn/shop/dungcuykhoa_tanphu/san-pham/?p=1'
browserdriver.get(link)
allrows_name=browserdriver.find_elements_by_xpath(element_name)
allrows_sold=browserdriver.find_elements_by_xpath(element_sold)
for row_name, row_sold in zip(allrows_name,allrows_sold):
    print( row_name.text +":::"+row_sold.text)
print("program end")
```

That works but the result of matching is incorrect due to missing value (null value) in allrows_sold

```
Túi chườm đá lạnh size lớn:::2
Combo 6 cây giấy lau mặt trong thẩm mỹ, spa:::3
Thước đo mắt - compa mắt:::7
Bộ giác hơi không dùng lửa Duy Thành YGH02 - Valy đen:::3
Máy đo tiểu đường OGCare chính hãng tặng 3 hộp que:::6
Hộp 25 que thử đường huyết OGCare date xa:::33
Túi chườm nóng lạnh đa năng Hướng Dương cỡ đại:::1
Bộ giác hơi không dùng lửa Duy Thành valy nâu:::2
Kính bảo hộ Spider chống bụi gió an toàn cho bé:::2
Máy đo đường huyết OGCare kèm 25 que thử:::15
Vớ y khoa, vớ tĩnh mạch Đức chính hãng - Vớ gối:::19
Vớ y khoa phòng ngừa và điều trị suy giãn tĩnh mạch vùng gối Jiani - Ý:::11
Vớ y khoa phòng ngừa và điều trị giãn tĩnh mạch Jiani - Vớ gối:::4
program end
```

As you can see, it works well until the third line where there is not value of sold quantity in allrows_sold
Now I want the program to key "0" into any item having null sold quantity (@class='s_b')

Plz, help me to find another solution for this matching problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just change the sold element `xpath` and checked if text value is null assigned 
`'0'`

```
element_name='//*[@class="name_product shop_color_hover"]'
element_price='//*[@class="current_price"]'
element_sold='//div[@class="social_box"]'
link='https://www.sendo.vn/shop/dungcuykhoa_tanphu/san-pham/?p=1'
browserdriver.get(link)
allrows_name=browserdriver.find_elements_by_xpath(element_name)
allrows_sold=browserdriver.find_elements_by_xpath(element_sold)

for row_name, row_sold in zip(allrows_name,allrows_sold):
    if row_sold.text!='':

       print( row_name.text +":::"+row_sold.text)
    else:

        print(row_name.text + ":::" + "0")
print("program end")
```

Output:

```
Túi chườm đá lạnh size lớn:::2
Combo 6 cây giấy lau mặt trong thẩm mỹ, spa:::3
Thước đo mắt - compa mắt:::0
Bộ giác hơi không dùng lửa Duy Thành YGH02 - Valy đen:::7
Máy đo tiểu đường OGCare chính hãng tặng 3 hộp que:::0
Hộp 25 que thử đường huyết OGCare date xa:::3
Túi chườm nóng lạnh đa năng Hướng Dương cỡ đại:::6
Bộ giác hơi không dùng lửa Duy Thành valy nâu:::33
Kính bảo hộ Spider chống bụi gió an toàn cho bé:::1
Máy đo đường huyết OGCare kèm 25 que thử:::2
Vớ y khoa, vớ tĩnh mạch Đức chính hãng - Vớ gối:::2
Vớ y khoa phòng ngừa và điều trị suy giãn tĩnh mạch vùng gối Jiani - Ý:::15
Vớ y khoa phòng ngừa và điều trị giãn tĩnh mạch Jiani - Vớ gối:::19
Vớ y khoa phòng ngừa và điều trị giãn tĩnh mạch Jiani - Vớ đùi:::11
Máy massage Mini Squirrel V-555 nhập khẩu chính hãng Hàn Quốc:::4
program end

Process finished with exit code 0
```